# What is the exact difference between CS and theoretical CS SE sites?

Tags: discussion, support

What is the exact difference between Computer Science and theoretical Computer Science StackExchange sites?

Does Computer Science really mean Applied Computert Science?

Comment: See also [What is the history of the Computer Science site?](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/215/what-is-the-history-of-the-computer-science-site), [How to make our cs community very different from the cstheory?](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-to-make-our-cs-community-very-different-from-the-cstheory)

Comment: there is a declared scope and a day-to-day scope.... the latter is found by reviewing/comparing many questions (historical/recent) on each site....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quote directly from the [help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page on cs.SE, and the [about](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/about) page on cstheory.SE:

> Computer Science Stack Exchange is for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science.

and

> Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional researchers in theoretical computer science and related fields.

cs.SE does have a broader range of acceptable topics than cstheory.SE, but the key difference if the level they're aimed at. cs.SE is for basically anyone interested in Computer Science (within scope). cstheory.SE is meant for *active researchers* in theoretical CS, and the questions should be not-too-far from research level work (included graduate level questions).

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!

Comment: Note that "theory" is interpreted in its academic sense, i.e. CS at the border to mathematics, not in it "street" sense (everything done at university). In fact, *most* academic computer science is *not* theoretical computer science.

Comment: A small correction: most graduate student level questions in theoretical computer science are welcome on cstheory as explained in the cstheory's on-topic help page, it is not a contentious issue as far as I know.

Comment: @Kaveh, adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @Luke, thanks :)